# setting Round scrollview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I wants to set rounded scrollview in iphone App.

The Same Effect is available on the following link of Apple store.
http://itunes.apple.com/app/iretrophone-rotary-dialer/id284700702?mt=8

I have tried horizontal and vertical scrollview.
IS it possible to set rounded scrollview or arch scrollview??

Thanks in Advance.
Any Idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the current `UIScrollView`, and its probably opening yourself up to a whole world of pain to do it yourself. IF you just want an animation of scrolling rainbow colours then I would probably just make an image-based animation.

If you need people to scroll through it like a scroll view would then that's going to be incredibly complicated to build. You're probably best off creating a looping image sequence which will run when the user scrolls over your image, or something similar. You can test for gestures. But you won't be able to add other objects and subviews.

Comment: No i don't want the animation. i have given the example of rainbow for your reference. In possible, Then plz suggest me better way to do that. Any Idea is greatly appreciated.